# Applying non-trivial matrix calculating without for-loop in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

Simply trying to find best way to compute this updated covariance matrix for the EM algorithm
[image]*

I have the algorithm developed, but using a for-loop. I'm trying to determine how to utilize Numpy vectorization.

```
cov_c = []
for cluster, u, w in zip(r.T, mu_c, total_weight):
    s = 0
    for n in range(len(d)):
        s += cluster[n]*np.outer(d[n] - u, d[n] - u)
    cov_c.append(s / w)
```

cov_c is a two element list, each with a covariance matrix (2x2)

```
    [array([[0.19, 0.23],[0.23, 0.39]]), 
     array([[4.05, -5.01,[-5.018,  6.22]])]
```

d and r are both two-dimensional array (weighted samples) d is the feature vector (2 features for 100 samples), where r is weights of each feature for 2 Gaussians

```
d.shape
(100, 2)
r.shape
(100, 2)
```

mu_c is two element list of mean vectors

```
mu_c
[array([ 0.24387682, -0.27793324]), array([ 2.37853451, -1.86454301])]
```

total weight is a normalization factor (simply 2 element 1d array):

```
total_weight
array([53.51779102, 46.48220898])
```

Any suggestions on how to vectorize this computation? Thanks!

- http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~vplab/courses/DVP/PDF/gmm.pdf

Comment: yes it did. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could make use of NumPy arrays to leverage vectorized ufunc operations. Also, since the number of columns in `d` is just `2`, we would simply use a loop along that axis (hence a loop of just two iterations). Thus, we would use sliced data instead of extending arrays in all directions, which would have incurred heavier memory congestion. We would still leverage `broadcasting` on the sliced data. Finally, we would make use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to replace the outer sum-reductions and this is probably where we would gain the most.

We would end up with something like this -

```
mu_c = np.asarray(mu_c)
total_weight = np.asarray(total_weight)

n = d.shape[1]
out = np.empty((n,2,2))
for i in range(n):
    du = d-mu_c[i]
    out[i] = np.einsum('i,ij,ik->jk',r[:,i],du,du)
cov_c_out = out/total_weight[:,None,None]
```

Alternatively, that `einsum` part could be replace by a matrix-multiplication step -

```
out[i] = (r[:,i,None]*du).T.dot(du)
```

For the sake of completeness or just fun, here's what a completely vectorized solution would be like, that's memory intensive and hence most probably slower -

```
dmuc = d[:,None,:]-mu_c
out = np.einsum('ij,ijk,ijl->jkl',r,dmuc,dmuc)
```

Also, play around with the `optimize` flag in `np.einsum` by setting it as `True` to use BLAS.

Comment: shouldn't the memory intensive solution actually be faster? i'm thinking of the usual CPU/memory trade-off and assuming that it holds in this case (and that the user *has* enough memory to support it)

Comment: @vlsd Well memory intensive with the compute staying constant isn't beneficial in terms performance because of the latency of data fetching. The memory intensiveness is more here on comparison because on one hand you have slicing which is just a view on existing 2D data vs broadcasting based memory intensive that creates a new 3D array.

Comment: I missed the part where the compute stays constant, I just *assumed* that a higher memory solution would have lower cycle count :)